# Toshiba TEC TPCL: looking for basic communication example

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, printer-control-language

I need to write some code that prints labels using Toshiba TEC TPCL language.
I have language documentation and I found a few SO topics, but everything I found is focused on the language itself, not on how I should communicate with the printer.

I mean, the printer can be connected through serial, usb or network.
If the printer is connected through serial, I think I simply need to open the serial port and start sending commands - but with what parameters?
For lan maybe I could open a tcp connection to port 9100 and send commands, although I'm not so sure about this.
For usb (the connection method I'm actually interested in) I have no clues.

I have some experience with Godex printers, where a dll is provided by Godex that takes care of actual communication, you simply have to call an "open connection" function with the desired connection method (serial, lan, usb) as a parameter.

With Toshiba I can't find anything like that, and I also can't find a usage example that shows the basic communication setup process.

I know that Toshiba provides BarTender (label designing software) that comes with an SDK, but I prefer not to use it, and go with pure TPCL.

Does anyone have experience on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TTEC's "BCP Print for .NET".
Tt includes BCPControl.dll

I think that the best idea is to contact your local TTEC office to get their help.

Rafal

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? I searched for "BCP Print for .NET" or "BCPControl.dll" on Google but I didn't find anything...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).